# why does my c++ code show segmentation fault

Tags: c++, error-handling, segmentation-fault, c++14

recently i was trying to solve this problem on codechef - https://www.codechef.com/problems/SUMTRIAN .  the custom input details for the problem are as follows .

[custom input details image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ennVQ.png)

**i designed the following code for the problem** :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void func()
{  
    vector<vector<int>> t;
   int i=0,j=0,rows=0;
   cin>>rows; // to input no. of rows 
              // i think for this cin it shows a seg fault
              // and also maybe for other cin lines

  for(i=0;i<rows;i++)//input the elements from custom input and store in 2D       
   for(j=0;j<=i;j++) //matrix
    cin>>t[i][j];

 for(i=rows-2;i>=0;i--)
 for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
 t[i][j]=t[i][j]+max(t[i+1][j],t[i+1][j+1]);

 cout<<endl<<t[0][0]; //element at this position will have max sum
 }

int main() {
    int t=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)//for t test cases
    func();

    return 0;
}
```

**Whenever i run this code it shows segmentation fault :**
[code output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2k0W7.png)

i tried to debug the code a little using **cout** statements before and after a **cin** statement and found that the **cout** before the **cin>>rows** statement gets executed but not the one after it . but having said that the cin statement : **cin>>t**  in main gets executed without any problem .

can someone please help me understand why do i encounter this weird seg fault .

Comment: Your vector is empty. `cin>>t[i][j];` accesses it out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must tell the vectors how much elements to store:

```
void func()
{  
    int i=0,j=0,rows=0;

    cin>>rows;

    vector<vector<int>> t(rows);

    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)  
    {
        t[i].resize(rows);

        for(j=0;j<=i;j++) 
            cin >> t[i][j];
    }
...
```

If you do not need a square matrix of rows x rows call resize with i + 1.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and decide if you want to accept it.